# regex for integer or double

Tags: java, regex

There is a string "12.2A12W99.0Z0.123Q9"
I need to find 3 groups: (double or int)(nondigit)(double or int)
So in the case of the sample, I would want this to happen:
    matcher.group (1) = "12.2"
    matcher.group (2) = "A"
    matcher.group (3) = "12"

My current regex only matches against integers: "^(\d+)(\D)(\d+)"
So I am looking to change the group (\d+) to something that will match against integers OR doubles.

I dont understand regex at all, so explaining like I'm 5 would be cool.

Comment: the first entry when searching the web returns: [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) and it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-
Your regular expression is only matching numeric characters. To also match the decimal point too you will need:

```
Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+")

private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
```

The . is escaped because this would match any character when unescaped.

Note: this will then only match numbers with a decimal point which is what you have in your example.

```
private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

public void testInteger() {
    Matcher m =p.matcher("10");

    assertTrue(m.find());
    assertEquals("10", m.group());
}

public void testDecimal() {
    Matcher m =p.matcher("10.99");

    assertTrue(m.find());
    assertEquals("10.99", m.group());
}
```

Comment: What's a `:-`? I can't rotate my mouth like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I want it to amtch against both integers and doubles, not just doubles. Is there a way to write a regex to do that?

Comment: Just now my edited answer and let me know your feedback

Comment: @YogeshTatwal But now I think the groups are messed up because of the extra brackets, I need matcher.group(1) to return the first number, matcher.group(2) to return the non-digit, etc. The extra brackets mess up the grouping.

Comment: As par your requirement i have edited it again